# Comparing 2 different scenarios on 2 different architectures when finding the max element of an array

Tags: c, optimization, cuda, opencl, gpgpu

Suppose we have the classic scenario where we need to find the max element (integers only) of an array, but not its position. Which of the following 2 code samples (which are placed inside a 'for' loop) runs faster on a CPU and which one on a GPU, and why?

```
if( array[i] > max)
  max = array[i];
```

and

```
max = 0.5 * ( a + b + abs(a-b));      //Where 'a' and 'b' refer to 'max' and 'array[i]'
```

Moreover, what really bothers me in the second block of code, is the 'abs' function call. Is there any way to calculate the absolute of value of a number only by using an arithmetic expression?

Comment: you mean something like  `a*( (a > 0) - (a < 0) )` ?

Comment: `abs(a-b)` can readily cause `int` overflow both as `a-b` and `abs()`.  Not a robust method. `0.5 *` can cause precision loss.  What is the value of speed with those functional issues vs. the well defined `if( array[i] > max)`?

Comment: This is really good but by 'arithmetic expression' i was referring to something without logical operators. Excuse me if i was being unclear.

Comment: If there exist a _better_ way to do `abs()` than using logical operators, the implementation of `abs()` likely uses that already.

Comment: Please show at least some research effort. Internet is full of ready-made code you can copy and analyze. As for your first block, comparing two `int` values is processor-inexpensive.

Comment: "runs faster" and "only by using an arithmetic expression" can be in conflict.  `fabs()` is a _function_ and not a _arithmetic expression_, yet it may compile to a speedy intrinsic instruction.  So what is the priority of your requirements?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Chux, speed is my priority.

Comment: 1. There is no general answer to this question.  It will depend on the specific compilers used.  It may also depend on the specific processor used.   2. This is almost certainly in the category of "misguided/premature" optimization.  3. It should be trivial to benchmark the difference, if any, for a specific case (specific processor, specific compiler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're really trying to ask about branchless vs. branching ways to do `m = max(m, array[i])`.  C compilers will already compile the `if()` version to branchless code (using `cmov`) depending on optimization settings.  It can even auto-vectorize to a packed compare or packed-max function.

Your `0.5 * abs()` version is obviously terrible (a lot slower than a conditional-move) because it converts to `double` and back.   rather than dividing by two with a right shift.

See the asm on [the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-O3++-Wall++-fno-verbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell+-mno-avx',source:'%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0A//+conversion+to/from+double,+and+an+FP+multiply,+in+the+loop-carried+dependency+chain%0Aint+maxarray_float(int+arr%5B%5D,+int+n)+%7B%0A++int+result+%3D+arr%5B0%5D%3B%0A++for+(int+i%3D0+%3B+i%3Cn%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A++++int+tmp+%3D+arr%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++result+%3D++0.5+*+(+result+%2B+tmp+%2B+abs(result-tmp))%3B%0A++%7D%0A++return+result%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A//+auto-vectorizes+to+PMAXSD,+or+without+SSE4.1,+to+pcmpgt+/+pand/por+emulation+of+the+same%0Aint+maxarray_if(int+arr%5B%5D,+int+n)+%7B%0A++int+result+%3D+arr%5B0%5D%3B%0A++for+(int+i%3D0+%3B+i%3Cn%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A++++int+tmp+%3D+arr%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++if+(result+%3C+tmp)%0A++++++result+%3D+tmp%3B%0A++%7D%0A++return+result%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

```
// auto-vectorizes to PMAXSD, or without SSE4.1, to pcmpgt / pand/por emulation of the same
int maxarray_if(int arr[], int n) {
  int result = arr[0];
  for (int i=0 ; i<n; ++i) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    if (result < tmp)
      result = tmp;
  }
  return result;
}
```

gcc 5.3 `-O3 -march=haswell -mno-avx` auto-vectorized inner loop:

```
.L13:
    add     eax, 1
    pmaxsd  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx]
    add     rdx, 16
    cmp     r8d, eax
    ja      .L13
```

Vs. the FP version:

```
    ... whole bunch of integer crap
    cvtsi2sd        xmm0, eax
    mulsd   xmm0, xmm1
    cvttsd2si       eax, xmm0
```

So the FP version is obviously complete garbage.

You'll get similar results for any target architecture.  The conversion to/from `double` isn't going to go away.  gcc keeps it even with `-ffast-math`.

Comment: So, if I divide with a right shift, am I at better from the 'if' option in terms of perforfance, or still slower?

Comment: @PanteleimonStamatakis: Still worse, because of potential integer overflow, like @ chux pointed out in comments.  As you could see if you tried it, [it doesn't autovectorize](https://godbolt.org/g/28Me4h), and compiles to more code than just a compare and `cmov`, whether you `/2` or `>>1`.

Answer (score 0):

Load balance it on cpu and gpu according to their work completion timing.

Lets assume tx is cpu time, ty is gpu time, wx is cpu work share percent, wy is gpu workshare percent.

```
Iteration 1
wx=0.5;  wy=0.5; // just a guess as 1 / (total number of devices)

Iteration 2
px= wx/tx; ----> compute power of cpu
py= wy/ty; ----> compute power of gpu
because doing work in less time means more


ptotal=px+py;

wx=px/ptotal;
wy=py/ptotal;

setting work share to exact power can alternate next shares
so you may need relaxation constant


wx=0.3 * (px/ptotal);
wy=0.3 * (py/ptotal);

so small changes in instantenous compute power won't bug this.

Iteration 3:

px= wx/tx;
py= wy/ty; 

ptotal=px+py;

wx=0.3 * (px/ptotal);
wy=0.3 * (py/ptotal);
```

but in opencl you would give them a proper local worksize and work shares must be done in resolution of local worksize.

```
global_range_x= nearest_multiple_of_256(wx * total_global_range);
global_range_y= nearest_multiple_of_256(wy * total_global_range);
```

if sum of global ranges is equal to total range, it is ok to compute offsets per device according to other devices total ranges.

if cpu has a computed range of 768 and gpu has range of 256, you could set their global offsets to 0(cpu) and 768(gpu) so they do not overlap.